# Difference between "bash executable" and "bash -c executable"

Tags: bash

My understanding is that `bash -c file` means the same thing as being in an interactive bash shell and calling `file`, where `bash file` means to interpret the file using bash (as if it were a shell script).  Is this accurate?  Is this the reason you cannot run `bash <executable>` because it will try to interpret the file as a shell script instead of forking and running exec file?

Comment: Exactly. With `bash -c` you are simply giving it a line of a script whatever it is (including another executable script), and with `bash file` you are simply giving it a file that *contains* the script code. Because executable bash scripts are (through the use of #! directive) called by bash interpreter anyway, calling `bash -c script.sh` is like doing `bash -c "bash script.sh"`.

Comment: @orion why not make that into an answer? Answering questions in comments is bad for everyone since the question will never be marked as answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, from [bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash):

> -c string
>
> Read and execute commands from string after processing the options,
>   then exit. Any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional
>   parameters, starting with $0.

So when you supply `-c` option, `bash` treat string after `-c` as a sequence of commands, then execute those commands in the child process environment. So when you call `bash -c file`, `bash` treat `file` as a command, find it by looking through `PATH` environment variable. If `file` is found, then execute it, otherwise command not found error will be raised.

When you called `bash file`, bash simply treat `file` as a [shell script](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Scripts), read and execute commands from `file`, then exit. Again, from [bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash):

> If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the -c nor
>   the -s option has been supplied, the first argument is assumed to be
>   the name of a file containing shell commands (see Shell Scripts). When
>   Bash is invoked in this fashion, $0 is set to the name of the file,
>   and the positional parameters are set to the remaining arguments. Bash
>   reads and executes commands from this file, then exits. Bash’s exit
>   status is the exit status of the last command executed in the script.
>   If no commands are executed, the exit status is 0.

So, your understanding is right.

Comment: In Bash's source code, in execute_cmd.c, the function shell_execve has the following comment:

  /* This file is executable.
     If it begins with #!, then help out people with losing operating
     systems.  Otherwise, check to see if it is a binary file by seeing
     if the contents of the first line (or up to 80 characters) are in the
     ASCII set.  If it's a text file, execute the contents as shell commands,
     otherwise return 126 (EX_BINARY_FILE). */

So basically it looks for a shebang or a magic number signifying an executable throwing an internal error on an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Just summary:

- `bash <file>` can execute only **shell scripts**
- `bash -c <file>` can execute **binaries**  (e.g. `/usr/bin/date`, `/usr/bin/echo`) and *executable* **shell scripts**

Comment: Not exactly. `<file>` in `bash -c <file>` needs to be executable. `<file>` in `bash  <file>` doesn't need to be executable.